# How to close the matlab background to start the program

Tags: matlab

I am running a few code files, the way to use the `matlab cli` is allowed in the background, now I need to stop it, for some special reason, I only want to stop a part of the program, so how do I use MATLAB to stop.

The sample code file runs as follows

```
## run.sh
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash < code1.m > res1.txt 2>&1 &
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash < code2.m > res2.txt 2>&1 &
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash < code3.m > res3.txt 2>&1 &
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash < code4.m > res4.txt 2>&1 &
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash < code5.m > res5.txt 2>&1 &
```

I need to stop `code4.m` and `code5.m`. I can't tell which program `code4.m and code5.m` is using the `kill` command

So, I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You may poll for a distinct event, e.g. easiest by checking for a particular file at a particular location, and if some magic pattern matches you may stop the process (this is not very elegant, but if it's just code for you it will do).

Depending on what you are doing (and assuming you run your code on Windows), you could also write the PID of the running Matlab processes to the registry, and use the tokens to identify which instance is running which code to kill it.